LimeTabular TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
I've started learning Lime. When I use LimeTabular form Interpret, I face a problem that I according to the standard complete the function but it doesn't work.
The error is TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
# %% Imports
from utils import DataLoader
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, accuracy_score
from interpret.blackbox import LimeTabular
from interpret import show

# %% Load and preprocess data
data_loader = DataLoader()
data_loader.load_dataset()
data_loader.preprocess_data()
# Split the data for evaluation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = data_loader.get_data_split()
# Oversample the train data
X_train, y_train = data_loader.oversample(X_train, y_train)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

# %% Fit blackbox model
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
print(f"F1 Score {f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')}")
print(f"Accuracy {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)}")

# %% Apply lime
# Initilize Lime for Tabular data
lime = LimeTabular(predict_fn=rf.predict_proba,
                   data=X_train, 
                   random_state=1)
# Get local explanations
lime_local = lime.explain_local(X_test[-20:], 
                                y_test[-20:], 
                                name='LIME')

show(lime_local)

# %%


Please provide the error message and traceback as code-formatted plain text in an [edit] to your question so we can understand your problem in more detail.

The error is TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
**In this problem you are calling constructor in line "data_loader = DataLoader()"
and it takes one argument that name is model so you have to pass it
another thing you can do it you can use default argument like this
class DataLoader:
def init(self,model=helper):
instead of helper you can use your model if it require somewhere or otherwise it can be None..
hope you will get it have a great day!!!
